# CSS change the bold test to have yellow background

Tags: html, css

I have an html test:

```
<body>
<div class="test">This is a <b>paragraph</b>.</div>
</body>
```

my css :

```
.test
{
color: #1F1FFF;
}
```

I want the bold text to be highlighted with yellow background, how do i do it with css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PuC9e/

```
.test b
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.test b
{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

or you can use inline style such as

```
<b style="background-color:yellow;">XYZ</b>
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NcAsz/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.test b
{
    background-color:#FF0;

}
</style>
<body>
<div class="test">This is a <b>paragraph</b>.</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more css property

```
.test b {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Please change the background color as per your need.